# How does integrated security work

Tags: entity-framework, wcf, sql-server-2012, connection-string, integrated-security

Recently my company released a new SQL standards document. Within this new standards document, I found the following line:

> Windows integrated security is preferred as far as possible

Hence, im my new wcf web service I have the following connection string (taken directly from web-app where used successfully):

```
<add name="ProcurementAdministrationPortalEntities"
     connectionString="metadata=res://*/ProcurementAdministrationPortalModel.csdl|res://*/ProcurementAdministrationPortalModel.ssdl|res://*/ProcurementAdministrationPortalModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=database-server;initial catalog=ProcurementAdministrationPortal_v2;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;"
     providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>
```

Now, when trying to use the service, I get the following error:

> Exception: The underlying provider failed on Open.
>
> InnerException: Login failed for user 'DOMAIN\D10604B77177C$'.

It's saying that the login failed for the domain/computer name. Does this mean that the machine where the web service is running on needs to be added to the permissions of the database? I am currently logged into AD on said machine with an account that is added to in the database. The account being 'DOMAIN\ANEL5'.

Comment: not the machine, but the account or group, yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the machine name is passed as the user ID it usually means that your application pool is running as System.  With Integrated Security = true, it tries to login with the computer object ID.  Change the app pool to use a domain user ID (we have an OU just for service accounts) and give that domain ID the required SQL permissions.